# How to bind to coordinates <onlineresourse>, in sld GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sld, image

I have coordinates and there is an image (link to png image), I need to bind it to the coordinates (onlineresource tag) in the GeoServer. An example of how to google maps here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

```
    <ExternalGraphic>
        <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
            xlink:href="http://mysite.com/tn_${strToLowerCase(STATE_ABBR)}.jpg">
        <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    </ExternalGraphic>
```

I want OnlineResource set as geo-referenced

Answer (score 2):

The external graphic will be drawn at the point of the feature if it is a point or the centroid of the geometry for lines and polygons.